# What is the real use of ternary operator in Java for the below case. Which will be more efficient?

Tags: java, operators, conditional-operator

Is Reassigning false to primitive boolean a good use of ternary operator?

```
boolean a = false;
```

Way 1 :

```
a = object.isAllowed() != null ? object.isAllowed() : false;
```

Way 2 :

```
if(object.isAllowed() != null) {
    a = object.isAllowed();
}
```

Kindly suggest which is a better way and why?

Comment: Those aren't entirely equivalent. The first will always overwrite `a`, whereas the second will only overwrite the value of `a` if `object.isAllowed() != null`.

Comment: Also, an `isAllowed` function returning `null` seems weird. That sounds like it should only return a Boolean value.

Comment: Cool. The variable can be overwritten with true since it already holds false. So is it good to use the Way 2 as above ? isAllowed will return a Boolean.

Comment: You should not care about efficiency at such places. If you care then check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35189815/12323248) answer. What you should care about is readability of your code. Do whatever is more readable.

Comment: `isAllowed()` should return a primitive `boolean` value.  Note in particular that a method that returns java.lang.Boolean must get named `getAllowed` rather than isAllowed in order to be Java Bean compliant.  However, it can be named isAllowed if its return value is primitive boolean.

Answer (score 1):

No, the simple solution for this would be;

```java
boolean a = object.isAllowed() != null && object.isAllowed();
```

This is assuming that object.isAllowed() returns a Boolean object that is nullable.

Comment: Or omit the null check and use `Boolean.TRUE.equals()`

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, `object.isAllowed()` returns either true or null. Since already you have assigned value of `a` as `false`, it's better not to assign the same value to the same variable (if you consider the efficiency of your code).

So way 2 is better in that case. Or you can also go with Jason's answer (it is more clear and readable).

Answer (score 0):

> Is Reassigning false to primitive boolean a good use of ternary operator?

In general, nothing wrong with reassigning value to a variable (if necessary), in fact variable's literal meaning is *changeable*.

One should just keep in mind that inefficient re-assigning of variable increases space complexity, ultimately affects program performance.

It does not related to ternary operator.

> Kindly suggest which is a better way and why?

Both have minor pros and cons Like:

**Way 1:**

*Pros*

1) Compact syntax

2) More professional

*Cons*

1) Inefficient reassigning of variable every time. Takes a *bit* more memory than traditional `if else`.

2) If multiple conditions involved, readability of code gets affected.

3) You must have to implement `else` part (:) of ternary operator

**Way 2:**

*Pros*

1) Takes efficient amount of memory. (Depending on how you wrote condition)

2) More readable where multiple conditions involved.

3) `else` part not mandatory

*Cons*

1) Lengthy syntax