# How do I covert this ternary statement to an if else statement? (Java)

Tags: java

Here is the ternary statement that I need help converting into an if/else statement:

```
char rightColor = necklace.charAt(i + 1 == necklace.length() ? 0 : i + 1);
```

Comment: By the way, the `char` type is obsolete, supplanted by Unicode code point integer numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35189762/642706

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do Ternary and If/Else compile to the same thing, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189762/do-ternary-and-if-else-compile-to-the-same-thing-why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways, it depends on your logic, here is one of the solution you can do:

```
int index;
if (i + 1 == necklace.length()) {
    index = 0;
} else {
    index = i + 1;
}
char rightColor = necklace.charAt(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator is equivalent to asking:

Is `i + 1` equal to `necklace.length`?

- If `true`, then the value `0` (at the left of `:`) is passed to the `charAt()` method.
- If `false`, then the value `i + 1` is passed.

So a verbose equivalent would be, for example:

```
char rightColor ;

if ( i + 1 == necklace.length() ) {
    rightColor = necklace.charAt(0) ;
} else {
    rightColor = necklace.charAt(i + 1) ;
}
```